# No such file or directory for virtualenv in bash script

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv

I am getting a `No such file or directory` when trying to activate my `virtualenv` in a script.

The project is called `hive` and it is under `/home/sys_hive/analytics/hive`

my `bin` directory is in `/home/sys_hive/analytics/hive/hive`

```
$ pwd
/home/sys_hive/analytics/hive/hive

$ ls 
run_scripts  utils

$ cd ..; ls
bin  include

Project structure:

  /utils
    prog.py
  /runscripts
    script.sh
```

Within script.sh

```
  #!/usr/bin/env bash
  source ../../bin/activate
  python -m utils.prog -a 1 -b 2  # not sure what to do here to call prog.py
  deactivate
```

1. Having issues with `source ../../bin/active`

   `ERROR: line 3: ../../bin/activate: No such file or directory`
2. I am not sure if I will be calling my python script correctly

Comment: where is Project with respect to bin and include? Add that to your question please.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz Updated! please let me know if there is anything else missing

Comment: Note that `..` is relative to *the directory the user is in when they run the script*, not relative to the directory the script itself is in. If you want to force changing the current directory to the script's location, or how to store that location in a shell variable, we already have lots of Q&A entries describing how to do that.

Comment: Seems to me that activate is just one level up from script.sh, so `source ../bin/activate` should work.